# How can I add custom logic for the title of a document in Blacklight?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blacklight

Instead of defining a single `title_field` I would like to display a custom title depending on the contents of a document. According to the [Blacklight Wiki](https://github.com/projectblacklight/blacklight/wiki/Configuration---Results-View#add-custom-logic-for-displaying-record-titles-in-search-results) this can be accomplished by setting `config.index.document_presenter_class` to a custom presenter:

```rb
# app/controllers/catalog_controller.rb
class CatalogController < ApplicationController
  ...
  configure_blacklight do |config|
    ...
    config.index.document_presenter_class = MyPresenter
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

Where the custom presenter overrides the `label` method:

```rb
# app/presenters/my_presenter.rb
class MyPresenter < Blacklight::IndexPresenter
  def label(field_or_string_or_proc, opts = {})
    # Assuming that :main_title and :sub_title are field names on the Solr document.
    document.first(:main_title) + " - " + document.first(:sub_title)
  end
end
```

When I do this my custom label method doesn't seem to get called, which I checked by adding a `puts` statement and a debugger breakpoint.

Is there something I could have missed or another way to display custom document titles?

Comment: You probably tried this, but have you restarted the application? I can't recall if a new Presenter would get autoloaded in dev mode or not.

Comment: @cdmo yes, restarting didn't help, but found a solution in the meantime. I'll add it as an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding the `heading` method in my presenter class worked for me:

```rb
# app/presenters/my_presenter.rb
class MyPresenter < Blacklight::IndexPresenter
  def heading
    # Assuming that :main_title and :sub_title are field names on the Solr document.
    document.first(:main_title) + " - " + document.first(:sub_title)
  end
end
```